# Get dimensions of objects within an image

Tags: image, image-recognition

i'm planning to build a web app where following feature is used: 
 
Imagine uploading an image, 
and the dimensions within the image need to be retrieved

e.g. I would like to know the height and width of the input field.
given the fact I can provide the base image sizes and aspect ratio's.

[image: Example image]

- How would one go about getting the marked dimensions out of the given image?
- is there an open API that could do this?
- Is this even a possiblity?

Comment: What do you mean by *"you can provide the base image sizes and aspect ratios"*? Please provide them and explain what they are.

Comment: If, when uploading the image i can provide the fact that the image is 300px by 800px. Can i determine the width and height of the button relative to the total picture size?